# Is there any property for the eigenvalues of an Hermitian matrix on which a well-structured binary mask has been applied?

Tags: eigenvalues, quantum-mechanics, hermitian

While working on a quantum-focused article, I came accross the following problem. Let $\rho$ be a positive, semi-definite, $2^{n+m}$-Hermitian matrix with unit trace ($\rho$ is a density matrix). Let $\rho_{\text{mask}}$ be the matrix resulting from the element-wise multiplication between a symmetric binary matrix $M$ and $\rho$. I'm interested by the quantity $T = \sum_i\left|\lambda_i\right|$ where the $\lambda_i$ are the eigenvalues of $\rho_{\text{mask}}$, counted with their multiplicity. Specifically, I would like to lower/upper-bound $T$. $T$ is (up to a multiplicative factor $2$) the trace distance between $\rho$ and $\rho_{\overline{\text{mask}}}$, where $\rho_{\overline{\text{mask}}}$ is the result of the element-wise multiplication of $\rho$ and the "inverse" mask $\mathbf{1}-M$.

To the best of my knowledge, there is no theorem which would help determining this quantity, even with stronger assumptions on $M$. For instance, I'm especially interested by $M$ having a structure like this, where a yellow square is a 0, and a violet square a 1:

[image: Structure of the binary mask for m=3 and n=2]

In this case, we have $m=3$ and $n=2$. In the general case, this matrix is a $2^{n+m}$ matrix, and the big yellow squares have size $2^n-1$. The other structural properties carry on for bigger $n$ and $m$.

I've managed to show that in the special case $\rho=\frac{1}{2^{n+m}}\mathbf{1}$, where $\mathbf{1}$ is the matrix with all coefficients equal to 1, then $T$ is lower-bounded by $\frac{\left(2^n-1\right)\,\left(2^m-1\right)}{2^{n+m-1}}$. To do so, I've studied the characteristic polynomial of $\rho_{\text{mask}}$ and showed that $-\frac{2^n-1}{2^{n+m}}$ is an eigenvalue of $\rho_{\text{mask}}$ with multiplicity at least $2^m-1$. Since $\rho_{\text{mask}}$ as nil trace, it follows that $T$ is at least twice $\left(2^m-1\right)\,\frac{2^n-1}{2^{n+m}}$.

However, in the general case, I'm stuck. Even with $n=m=1$, I can't seem to find any relations between, say, eigenvalues of $\rho$ and those of $\rho_{\text{mask}}$.

Is there any theorem I'm unaware of that could be applied to this case?